# reading from multiple imap.gmail.com from the same fetchmail client

Tags: connection, imap, polling, gmail-imap, fetchmail

For my portfolio software I have been using `fetchmail` to read from a Google email account over IMAP and life has been great.  Thanks to the miracle of **idle** connection supported by imap3, my triggers fire in near-realtime due to server push, much sooner than periodic polling would allow otherwise.

In my basic `.fetchmailrc` setup, in which a brokerage customer's account emails trade notifications to a dedicated Gmail/Google Apps box, I've had

```
poll imap.gmail.com proto imap user "youraddress@yourdomain-OR-gmail.com" pass "yoMama"  keep nofetchall ssl  idle mimedecode limit 29000 no rewrite mda "myCustomSpecialMDAhandler.sh  %F %T"
```

Trouble is, now I need to support reading from multiple email boxes, and hand off the emails to other specialized MDA scripts I wrote.  No problem, just add more **poll** lines to `.fetchmailrc`, right?  Well that doesn't work when the other accounts also use **imap.gmail.com**.  What ends up happening is that while one account reads fine (and not necessary the first one listed, though usually yes), the other is getting *"socket error"* all day and the emails remain untouched, unread.  I can't figure out why and not even sure if it's some mechanism at `imap.gmail.com` or not, eg. limiting to one IMAP connection from a host.  That doesn't seem right since I have kept IMAP connections to many separate Gmail & Google Apps accounts from the same client for years (like **Thunderbird**) and never noticed this exclusivity problem.

I haven't tried launching multiple fetchmail daemons using separate **-f** config files (assuming they wouldn't conflict), or deploying one or more getmail and other similar email fetchers in addition.  Still trying to avoid that kind of mess--unscaleable the more boxes I have to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the reference offhand but somewhere in `fetchmail`'s docs I recall reading that **idle** is not so much an **imap** feature as a fetchmail optional trick, which has a (nasty for me) side effect of choking off all other defined accounts from polling until the connection is cut off by some external event or timeout.  So at least that would vindicate Google.

Credit to [Carl's Whine Rack](http://mbrisby.blogspot.com/2007/11/fetchmail-for-gmail.html) blog for some tips.

For now I use `killall fetchmail; fetchmail -f fetcher.$[$RANDOM % $numaccounts].rc` periodically from `crontab` to cycle reading accounts each defined individually in `fetcher.1.rc`, `fetcher.2.rc`, etc.   Acceptable while email events are relatively infrequent.